# ELSEIF statement help

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have an email going out to contacts.  Some contacts are associated with 1 organization, some with multiple and some without association.

I have this code snippet, but I'm having trouble understanding how to make this section of the email dynamic based on the number of rows match.

```
 <p>As a member of these organizations:</p>
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("Contact_Key") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */

set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("ENT.User_Organization",@numRowsToReturn,"Organization_Id","Contact_key", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)]%%

%%[if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @orgid, @DEColumn2`
    set @row = row(@rows,@i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @orgid = field(@row,"Organization_Id")
    SET @orgname = LookUp('ENT.Organizations', 'Name', 'Id', @orgid)

    ]%%
    <ul style="margin-left:30px;">
      <li> %%=v(@orgname)=%%</li>
                    </ul>
    %%[ 
  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

our sports community

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Desired outcome is to have 3 different content options based on the @rowCount (if 0 display this, if 1 display this, if >1 display this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the below should give you want you need.  I moved your `<ul>` outside the for loop so that there is not a new unordered list for every row, but each row is still added as a list item.

```
<p>As a member of these organizations:</p>
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("Contact_Key") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */

set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("ENT.User_Organization",@numRowsToReturn,"Organization_Id","Contact_key", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)]%%

%%[if @rowCount == 1 then

var @orgid
    set @row = row(@rows,1) /* get row based on counter */
    set @orgid = field(@row,"Organization_Id")
    SET @orgname = LookUp('ENT.Organizations', 'Name', 'Id', @orgid)

]%%
    <ul style="margin-left:30px;">
      <li> %%=v(@orgname)=%%</li>
    </ul>
%%[ elseif @rowCount > 1 then]%%

<ul style="margin-left:30px;">

%%[for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @orgid
    set @row = row(@rows,@i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @orgid = field(@row,"Organization_Id")
    SET @orgname = LookUp('ENT.Organizations', 'Name', 'Id', @orgid)
]%%
      <li> %%=v(@orgname)=%%</li>
%%[ next @i ]%%

</ul>

%%[ else ]%%

our sports community

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: That did exactly the right thing.  I had my nesting formatted incorrectly.  Updating code above due to unnecessary variable.